# TypeError : undefined is not a function Array.reduce

Tags: javascript

Below code is converting object into {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4","e":"5"}, in reduce it is looping through the array and generates the desired output. But then reduce throws TypeError : undefined is not a function.

I have gone through many links but those are not the solution for my error.

Any type of help is welcome.

Please check the code snippet below

```js
let a= {
    "a": ["1", "2"],
    "b": ["2", "2"],
    "c": ["3", "2"],
    "d": ["4", "2"],
    "e": ["5", "2"]
}

const b= Object.assign(...Object.entries(a).map(value => value.map((value1, index) => index == 0 ? value1 : value1[0])).reduce((a, c) => {
    //console.log('c', c);
    a[c[0]] = c[1];
    console.log(a);
    return a;
}, {}));
```

Comment: What's your desired output for `b`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's in the question. They clearly and directly state their desired output is: `{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4","e":"5"}`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance my desired output is {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4","e":"5"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to attempting to spread an object into an argument list:

```js
let a = {
  "a": ["1", "2"],
  "b": ["2", "2"],
  "c": ["3", "2"],
  "d": ["4", "2"],
  "e": ["5", "2"]
}

const reduceResult = Object.entries(a)
  .map(value => value
    .map((value1, index) => index == 0 ? value1 : value1[0])
  )
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c[0]] = c[1];
    return a;
  }, {});

console.log('about to Object.assign');
const b = Object.assign(
  ...reduceResult
);
```

Objects can't be spread into argument lists - objects can be only spread into other objects, eg

```
const b = { ...reduceResult };
```

But there's no need for spreading - just take the result of `reduce` by itself, and you have what you need. You can also simplify the code by removing the two `.map`s, and just using `reduce` by itself:

```js
let a = {
  "a": ["1", "2"],
  "b": ["2", "2"],
  "c": ["3", "2"],
  "d": ["4", "2"],
  "e": ["5", "2"]
}

const b = Object.entries(a)
  .reduce((acc, [key, [firstValue]]) => ({...acc, [key]: firstValue}), {})
  
console.log(b);
```